# How to get the plane password of Django admin user in pre_save signal when creating user from admin panel?

Tags: django, authentication, hash, wagtail, abstractuser

I need to log Django admin users in 3ed party authentication service. For that I need plane password without hashing. Here I used pre_save signal. That approach works well when I create an API endpoint for registration. But when I create an admin user from Django it always comes with defalut hashed password.

Any idea how to get the plane password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the `request` object to get that data.

You can use `@hooks.register('before_create_user')` to register a method to run before creating the user and get the password using `password=request.POST['password1']`. Keep in mind that, this hook runs when form loaded and also when form submitted. To get the password, you need to run this only when form submitted.

```py
@hooks.register('before_create_user')
def before_create(request: 'HttpRequest') -> 'HttpResponse':
    if request.method != 'POST': 
        return    # Ignore execution when form loads
    body = request.POST
    form = get_user_creation_form()(body, request.FILES)    # Get the associated form
    if not form.is_valid():
        return     # If the form submission is invalid, return
    password=body['password1']    # Get raw password
```